# Nested struct allocating memory

Tags: c, memory, struct, malloc

I have 2 structs:

The first:

```
 struct Link
    {
        frame_t *frame;
        struct Link *next;
    };

    typedef struct Link link_t;
```

And the second:

```
struct Frame
{
    char            *name;
    unsigned int    duration;
    char            *path;  // may change to FILE*
};

typedef struct Frame frame_t;
```

I try with function to allocate memory for Link struct and its not work.

Call to function:

```
link_t* list = NULL;
    list = AddItemToList(list);
```

And this is the function :

```
link_t* AddItemToList(link_t* item)
{
    if (item == NULL)
    {
        item = (link_t*)calloc(1, sizeof(link_t) );

        item->frame = (frame_t*)calloc(1, sizeof(frame_t));


        printf("Please insert frame path: ");
        scanf("%s", item->frame->path);

        printf("Please insert frame duration(in miliseconds): ");
        scanf("%d", item->frame->duration);

        printf("Please choose a name for that frame: ");
        scanf("%s", item->frame->name);
    }
    else item->next = AddItemToList(item-> next);
    return item;
}
```

Comment: After you've fixed the memory allocation problem, you also need to fix `scanf("%d", item->frame->duration)` to `scanf("%d", &item->frame->duration)`.  You should also validate that the memory allocations and all the calls to `scanf()` work, handling errors appropriately.  In general, it is better to separate I/O from things like list manipulation, but that can be left for later.

Answer (score 3):

You've never `alloc`'d `name` or `path` in your `Link` struct.  You're `scanf`ing into uninitialized memory.

```
item->frame = (frame_t*)calloc(1, sizeof(frame_t));

// You need to add something like:
item->frame->name = (char *)calloc(1, some_string_size);
item->frame->path = (char *)calloc(1, some_string_size);
```